# How do i sum from one to million using min,max,and sum? (in loop)

Tags: python, iteration

the question: Make a list of the numbers from one to one million, and then use
`min()` and `max()` to make sure your list actually starts at one and ends at one million. Also, use
the sum() function to see how quickly Python can add a million numbers.

So here's my initial code, I do not know how to use min max or sum in this case:

```
one_million = []
for numbers in range(0,1000000):
    counting = numbers+1
    one_million.append(counting)
    print(one_million)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it step by step.

> Make a list of the numbers from one to one million

```py
numbers = list(range(1, 1000000 + 1)) # add 1 to upper bound since range is inclusive-exclusive
```

> and then use min() and max() to make sure your list actually starts at one and ends at one million

```py
assert min(numbers) == 1
assert max(numbers) == 1000000
```

> Also, use the sum() function to see how quickly python can add a million numbers

```py
total = sum(numbers)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

`range` supports min, max and sum, so you don't need any loop to do this:

```
numbers = range(1,1000001) #Note that range gives you a number UP TO the last number
print(max(numbers))
print(min(numbers))
print(sum(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy

```
million = [n for n in range(0, 1000000 + 1)]
million_sum = sum(million)
print(million_sum)
assert min(numbers) == 1
assert max(numbers) == 1000000
```

Comment: Note: This would break because `million` wouldn't contain what you might think it would.

Comment: @KirkStrauser What would `million` contain then?

Comment: A list of the numbers from 0 to 999,999.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing the Python Crash Course book because this is project 4-5. I came across your post while I was looking for documentation on min and max. I thought it was great to see someone else working on the same problem so I  thought I would share my code. I came up with this:

```
million_list = []

for num in range(1,1_000_001):
    million_list.append(num)

print(min(million_list))
print(max(million_list))
print(sum(million_list))
```

JeffUK's answer is nice. Thanks for the info about range not requiring a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = list(range(1,1000001))

print(min(numbers))
print(max(numbers))

print(sum(numbers))
```

#also reading the book!